# What is $(\lnot p \implies q)$ relative to $(p \implies q)$? Does this relation (between one conditional and the other) have a name?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, propositional-calculus

Relative to $(p \implies q)$, the expression $(\lnot p \implies \lnot q)$  is the converse, since the second conditional is equivalent to $(q \implies p)$ (by contraposition).

Does the relation between $(\lnot p \implies q)$ and $(p \implies q)$ have a name? What is the first expression relative to the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(\lnot p \implies q)$ is equivalent to $(p \lor q)$, the relationship between   $(\lnot p \implies q)$ and $(p \implies q)$ is the same as the relationship between $(p \lor q)$ and $(p \implies q)$. But since these are two different connectives there is no need to have a name for the relationship between them.